# Identifying current main DHCP server

Tags: dhcp, failover, dhcp-server, failovercluster

There are two DHCP server of the same IP address example.(10.100.9.12 and 10.100.9.13).
The gateway, subnet mask, and DNS is the same.
The current DHCP are running on Vlan9.
Is there any possible way to tell which one the main DHCP and which one is the backup one?

PS. In the given scenario the I'm assume both DHCP are redundant to each other and can perform Failback, Failover relationship.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "main" DHCP server in a DHCP cluster for say.

If you are using DHCP server failover relationship as a way to make DHCP highly available, which probably you are, you can open DHCP management console and navigate to the configuration of the failover relationships. It has a direction, from one to the other.

It can be load balanced with variable present range of DHCP usage (20%/80%, 50%/50%, 70%/30% ...), or it can be in a hot standby failover relationship.

Failover relationships are assigned per DHCP scope and not the whole DHCP server, you can have multiple DHCP failover relationships defined. Very important note, DHCP server settings are not shared between server, only DHCP scope settings.

If you are using hot standby failover relationship, the hot DHCP server can be considered the "main" DHCP server, but only for the DHCP scopes that are in that particular failover relationships is defined.

If you want to know witch DHCP server is the one that leased a IP adress to your client machine network interface just open `cmd.exe` and type:

```
ipconfig /all
```

And under DHCP Server in your active network interface you will find IP address of a DHCP server.

#### Example:

[image]